# How can I detect unterminated comment and write an error message saying "Error: line X: unterminated comment" to the standard error stream in my code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void m_cmnt(FILE *fp) {
    int prev;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (prev == '*' && ch == '/') {
            return;
        } else
            prev = ch;
    }
}

int main(int c, char **arr) {
    FILE *fp, *np;
    int ch, prev;
    bool String = 0;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    np = fopen("temp.txt", "w");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid/No Filename given as Argument ! \n");
        return 1;
    }
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (!String) {
            if (ch == '/') {
                prev = ch;
                ch = getc(fp);
                switch (ch) {
                case '*':
                    /* if(ch != 'a') putc('h', np); */
                    m_cmnt(fp);
                    putc(' ', np);
                    break;
                default:
                    putc(prev, np);
                    putc(ch, np);
                    break;
                }
            } else
                putc(ch, np);
        } else
            putc(ch, np);

        if (ch == '\"' || ch == '\'')
            String = !String;
        prev = ch;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(np);
    remove(arr[1]);
    //rename("temp.txt", arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

This is a simple de-commenting C program (which is C pre-processor job). I was struggling adding a feature to write an error message when detecting unterminated comment (`/* example`) to the standard error stream. The error should say something like `Error: line X: unterminated comment` where X is the line number the error occurred. I have been trying this for days now and I can't make any progress and I am highly frustrated. So please someone help me with simple and to the point answer.

```
test.txt 

hello\nworld
Me/*some\ncomment*/again
```

The result of test.txt after the program run should be like

```
hello
world
me
again
```

Both of them are in separate line because \n is present in each case. But what I am getting right now is

```
hello\nworld
Me again
```

Comment: 1. You need to count newlines read so far so you can tell what line number you're on. 2. When you see `/*`, note the line number. 3. If you get to `EOF` before seeing `*/`, report an error with the line number you noted in step 2.

Comment: @ jamesdlin  I understand how the logic works, I just couldn't find a proper way to implement it. Any help on that?

Comment: Which part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: first where do I put the condition to check the unterminalted comment? and do I use another while loop to check for the EOF?

Comment: Your problem is very specific, you want to perform a transformation that is different from just stripping comments from a C source file. Replacing `\n` by a newline, rejecting nested comments and replacing comments by ` ` or newline depending on their contents... Where does this problem come from? What is the precise problem statement?

Comment: It is an exercise given by my instructor just to challenge our self and for fun. I have completed all the tasks except for the "\n" thing. And I just understand the unterminated comment thing so ignore what I posted about the second test file(test2.txt). So if you can help me on the newline thing that will conclude my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `m_cmnt()` function to output the error message if it encounters `EOF` while scanning for `*/`:

```
void m_cmnt(FILE *fp) {
    int prev, ch;
    for (prev = 0; (ch = getc(fp)) != EOF; prev = ch) {
        if (prev == '*' && ch == '/')
            return;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "error: unterminated comment\n");
}
```

If you want to output the line number, you must keep track of the line count everywhere.

Note also that you should handle `//` comments too and parse the strings more accurately, handling escape sequences.

Here is a version with line number handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* skip a C multi-line comment, return the last byte read or EOF */
int m_cmnt(FILE *fp, int *lineno_p) {
    int prev, ch, replacement = ' ';
    for (prev = 0; (ch = getc(fp)) != EOF; prev = ch) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
            replacement = '\n';
            ++*lineno_p;
        }
        if (prev == '*' && ch == '/')
            return replacement;
    }
    return EOF;
}

int main(int c, char **arr) {
    FILE *fp, *np;
    int ch;
    bool String = 0;
    const char *filename = "test.txt";
    int lineno = 1;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    np = fopen("temp.txt", "w");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open input file %s\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n')
            lineno++;
        if (!String) {
            if (ch == '/') {
                ch = getc(fp);
                if (ch == '\n')
                    lineno++;
                if (ch == '*') {
                    int startline = lineno;
                    ch = m_cmnt(fp, &lineno);
                    if (ch == EOF) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: error: unterminated comment started on line %d\n",
                                filename, *lineno, startline);
                        break;
                    }
                    putc(ch, np);
                } else {
                    putc('/', np);
                    putc(ch, np);
                }
            } else {
                putc(ch, np);
            }
        } else {
            putc(ch, np);
        }

        if (ch == '\"' || ch == '\'')
            String = !String;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(np);
    remove(arr[1]);
    //rename("temp.txt", arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

For illustration, here is a more complete program that handles all special cases for character and string constants and escaped newlines:

```
/* strip C comments by chqrlie */

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* read the next byte from the C source file, handing escaped newlines */
int getcpp(FILE *fp, int *lineno_p) {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) == '\\') {
        if ((ch = getc(fp)) != '\n') {
            ungetc(ch, fp);
            return '\\';
        }
        ++*lineno_p;
    }
    if (ch == '\n')
        ++*lineno_p;
    return ch;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = stdin, *ft = stdout;
    const char *filename = "<stdin>";
    int ch, lineno;

    if (argc > 1) {
        if ((fp = fopen(filename = argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file %s: %s\n",
                    filename, strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        if ((ft = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open output file %s: %s\n",
                    argv[2], strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }
    lineno = 1;
    while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF) {
        int startline = lineno;
        if (ch == '/') {
            if ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) == '/') {
                /* single-line comment */
                while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
                    continue;
                if (ch == EOF) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unterminated single line comment\n",
                            filename, startline);
                    break;
                }
                putc('\n', ft);  /* replace comment with newline */
                continue;
            }
            if (ch == '*') {
                /* multi-line comment */
                int lastc = 0, replacement = ' ';
                while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF) {
                    if (ch == '/' && lastc == '*') {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (ch == '\n')
                        replacement = '\n';
                    lastc = ch;
                }
                if (ch == EOF) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unterminated comment\n",
                            filename, startline);
                    break;
                }
                putc(replacement, ft);  /* replace comment with single space */
                continue;
            }
            putc('/', ft);
            /* keep parsing to handle n/"a//"[i] */
        }
        if (ch == '\'' || ch == '"') {
            int sep = ch;
            const char *const_type = (ch == '"') ? "string" : "character";

            putc(sep, ft);
            while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF) {
                putc(ch, ft);
                if (ch == sep)
                    break;;
                if (ch == '\\') {
                    if ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) == EOF)
                        break;
                    putc(ch, ft);
                }
                if (ch == '\n') {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unescaped newline in %s constant\n",
                            filename, lineno - 1, const_type);
                    /* This is a syntax error but keep going as if constant was terminated */
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ch == EOF) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unterminated %s constant\n",
                        filename, startline, const_type);
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
        putc(ch, ft);
    }
    if (fp != stdin)
        fclose(fp);
    if (ft != stdout)
        fclose(ft);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The specification says not to handle // comments. And how can I handle escape character like \n for both comment and non comment parts? For example A/*bc\n*/D the result should be A new line D (A and D in separate lines). I tried adding          
                                        if(ch == ' \n ')
                                        putc(' \n ', np);  in the m_cmnt function but not working.

Comment: `\n` inside a comment is just 2 ordinary characters. Handling `\"` inside a string would prevent misinterpreting it for the end of the string. Character constants require special processing as well because neither `'"'` nor `'\"'` is the start of a string.

Comment: sorry, I am not getting what you are saying. Can you explain?

Comment: When you are parsing a string, you stop at the `"` character. This is incorrect if the string is `"hello \"james"`. you will mistakenly switch out of `String` mode after `\"` and mistakenly switch back into string mode at the end if the string, copying the rest of the program, including its comments.

Comment: The above code has some bug. It won't generate error for if a terminated comment comes after unterminated comment. why is that happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: @pepedeneke: There should never be a terminated comment after an unterminated one since we are at end of file already. I modified the code to stop parsing at the first occurrence of `EOF`.

Comment: @ chqrlie Wow this is a whole new code and very complicated.

Comment: @ chqrlie  Can you please edit the first one just to deal with the terminated comment after unterminated and to only to handle \n character for both occurrence of inside a comment and out side a comment? The last code is hard to understand for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @pepedeneke: There can be no such thing as a terminated comment after an unterminated one. An unterminated comment can only occur at the end of the file, hence there is nothing after it. The complete code already handles newlines inside and outside comments. The new code is not so complicated, it relies on a utility function to handle escaped newlines and update the line number.

Comment: @ chqrlie The program do not handle \n character. By handle I mean when ever it encounters \n( either in side a comment or not) it should provide a new line. For example A\nB should make A and B in separate lines. Similarly if it is like A/*CD\nE*/B, A and B will be in separate lines. The only case where \n should be interpreted as a normal character is if it is inside double or single quote. I know it is weird but that is what I am trying to achieve. The above program does neither of this tasks. So can you help me on that?

Comment: @Brook: it makes sense. I modified both programs in the answer to provide this functionality. Look at the `replacement` variable: by default the comment is replaced with a single space but if it contains an unescaped newline, it will be replaced by a newline. I believe it is incorrect because it will break macros like `#define MACRO A/*xx\nyy*/B` that should expand to `A B`. In the stripped output, the macro will just expand to `A` and there will be a `B` on a separate line causing a syntax error.

Comment: @ chqrlie I don't think you understand me. When I run your code with a test file having \n character it just print it as \n. The \n is not replace with new line

Comment: @Brook: you are right, I do not understand the problem. Can you post an EDIT to the question with the test file contents, the expected output and the current unexpected output.

Comment: @ chqrlie I have edited the question with the inputs and expected result. I want to achieve this in the first code if possible. if not, just edit you code.